# How do I get the address of the value that a pointer is pointing to in C?

Tags: c, memory

I'm trying to get the address of a value which I'm not allowed to directly reference to.

```
int main() {
  int a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  int* ptr   = &arr[0];
  // ptr is incremented an unknown number of times
}
```

After the pointer has moved an unknown number of times, I need to know the address of the value the pointer is pointing to. Say if *ptr is now 3, I need to know the address of 3 without referencing the array. Is it possible?

Comment: `printf("%p\n", (void*) ptr);` should print the address of whatever `int` that `ptr` is pointing at.

Comment: What makes this question confusing and difficult to answer is your confusion about addresses and pointers; they cannot point at _values_, only _objects_, _functions_ or _nothing_...

Comment: Sitenote: `int a = {1, 2, 3, 4};` isn't a valid declaration of an array and `&arr[0]` takes the address of the first element in `arr` which is undeclared.

Comment: If I'm not completely confused, the value in the pointer is the address of the value that the pointer points at, which makes the question autologous.  If you're asking for the address of the start of the array, then that's a harder question to answer, but it isn't self-evidently the question you're asking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "tautologous"

Comment: `int a =` needs to be `int a[] =`

Comment: The address of `*ptr` is the value of `ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An address must point at an object or function, and is thus also known as a *pointer to object or function*. Let's deconstruct your question into premises:

¹/ you have an `int`, just one (**not** an array) with extra (erroneous) initialisers. That's a bit strange. Maybe you meant `int a[] = /* ... */`. On this note, there is no `3` stored because you only have space for **one** value in this object.

²/ you have a pointer to `int` object, this is called `ptr` and it's initialised to `&a[0]`, which is a reference op `&a` combined with a dereference op (`[0]`); these ops cancel each other out so your `ptr` declaration is actually equivalent to `int *ptr = a;`, which is also erroneous. Perhaps you meant `int *ptr = &a;` or, assuming you corrected the declaration for `a` (as per point 1), then your code (or the shorthand version, without the unnecessary dereference+reference) is okay.

> I need to know the address of the value the pointer is pointing to.

As previously noted, pointers don't point at values; they point at objects or functions (or nothing or garbage, both exceptions for which this question isn't relevant)... and addresses are pointers that point at objects or functions, so if you have a pointer pointing at an object **you already have the address**.

> Say if *ptr is now 3, I need to know the address of 3 without referencing the array.

**You already have the address**, and you're dereferencing it (`*ptr`) to obtain the value; `ptr` **is storing an address**, right? This is why Jonathan Leffler commented describing this question as *tautologous*; the very *pointer* you dereference to obtain the value is also (by definition) an *address* for the object you intended to be storing 3.

Your confusion is common and (among other common confusions that you're bound to ask about) would be best corrected by a decent textbook, such as K&R2e (do the exercises as you stumble across them). Alternatively, there are literally hundreds of frequently asked questions; you could read the 220ish pages and it'd be quicker and more reliable than asking all of these questions and trusting all of the answers...